# Partial view never affects site after upload and IIS reset

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm including a partial view in one of the pages of my MVC4 site which when deployed, even after a restart of the web site and recycling of the app pool, never seems to affect the site

I'm wondering if this is caching coming into play

I ended up including the content of the partial view in the page iteself and that seems to have worked but I'd rather have the partial view as I'd like to use the view in other parts of the site

The question is, does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening? I've been pulling my hair out trying to get a view to post the correct data, only to realise that some of the hidden inputs are just missing because the partial view has not been refreshed

**EDIT:**

Ok now I have a need to use this partial view in more than once place. On my dev environment the partial is rendering correctly. Uploading to the server doesn't seem to have any effect, but what's worse, deleting the partial view from the server also has the same issue.

My site still thinks the file is there and complains about the model type passed to the view now (I changed the model type in the view - all working fine on my local dev) - why does it still think the file is there?

I deleted one of the parent views to see if the site carried on working, but as soon as I delete any other file, the site is affected. Why is this particular file giving me trouble? It's as if the server has cached it at the file system level and is supplying the wrong file content to ASP.NET

I'm going to try renaming the file next

Comment: I had a similar issue yesterday when publishing. Here what I did: 1) Stop the IIS, 2) Clear the IIS cache and then 3) Publish the App. Somehow the View didn't update when I publish with the pool rolling.

Comment: Even stranger, now the view renders correctly, but one of the hidden inputs always has the same value no matter what the model contains (the model sets the value for the hidden input). I'm going bald as we speak! Other hidden inputs are correctly getting their values set from the model - I know the correct values are being posted because a) I can see them in the post and b) the correct items are displayed in the catalog for the chosen page number, but the page number still says 1!

Comment: Ok so a page rename has sorted the original issue, and the issue I just described was due to a coding error (I did something stupid in the code which only presented itself in certain conditions) - but thanks for the tip - it might come in handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so renaming the file appears to have worked.

I didn't try Fals suggestion but I might try that next time, strange behaviour I'm not going to try and understand why at this point!